# Get data attribute from button to modal in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angularjs-directive

I want to click on button then open Modal and pass data-img_id to display in my Modal id="myModalimgEdit" but it's not working i use laravel with angularjs.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button my-directive data-toggle="modal" data-img_id="hello world" data-target="#myModalimgEdit">
     My button directive
  </button>
</div>
```

My Modal in the same blade with button

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade text-xs-left" id="myModalimgEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
         aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Add
                        New Image Slide</h4>
                </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        {{igm_idd}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- END MODAL -->
```

My Angularjs

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function () {
          scope.igm_idd=attrs.imgId;
        })
      }
    }
});
```

Any solution for these?

Comment: You should use `ui bootstrap` - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. Also remeber that AngularJS was made for single page application. It's not a good idea to mix it with a PHP MVC Framework.

Comment: @lin Can you show me your answer please

Comment: I could but this one would based on `ui bootstrap`, would that be ok for you?

Comment: @lin ohh thank i use angularjs for pagination by no refresh page and easy to find data in table only. Can you guide me i use laravel what is the best way to create pagination the same like angularjs but not datatable

Comment: This is a abuse of AngularJS and Laravel. This guide will help you: https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application

Comment: @lin if you can answer please because i stuck for a day with my project

Comment: As i said, i can give you an anwer based on `ui bootstrap`.

Comment: @lin Thank you very much for your guide

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know attributes with slashes get transformed to camelCase when passed to the directive. Try `attrs.imgId`.

But all you are doing here is setting a scope variable inside your directive.

You should do 2 things:

Create a component for your modal:

```
myApp.component('modal', {
  template: '<!-- Modal --><div class="modal fade text-xs-left" ... {{igm_idd}} <!-- END MODAL -->',
  controller: ['$scope', 'modalService', function($scope, modalService) {
    $scope.igm_idd = modalService.getImage();
  }]
});
```

Create a service to make communication between your directive and your component work

```
myApp.service("modalSerivce", function () {
  var image;

  this.setImage = function(img) {
    image = img;
  };
  this.getImage = function() {
    return image;
  };
});
```

Then you can create your modal with `<modal></modal>` and call `modalService.setImage(attrs.imgId);` in your directive.

Your directive of course needs to get the newly created service injected:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', ['modalService', function (modalservice) { 
...
}]);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but i still don't get it

Comment: Just place a `debugger;` right before `element.on...` and open the dev tools ... you will see what is in the attrs variable, so you can fix the access to your data value. But even if you get this value you will not have access to the scope of your modal. Thats why you should vreate a component or at least define a controller with `ng-controller` that has access to that scope. You will need the service anyway if you do not want to use hacks and follow the angular way.